# What happened to Pseudo?

Tags: lore, npc, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, mutants-and-masterminds

Pseudo was a heroic Grue metamorph in 2E *Freedom City*'s Freedom League (I have a vague memory that he was not in the 1E book, but I might be wrong on that count). In the 3E *Freedom City* book, he's no longer part of the team, and the only mention of him in the *Cosmic Handbook* is a quick side-reference that he was a rogue agent from the Grue Unity. Poking around the other books I own, as well as the Patreon posts, I've found no reference to what happened to him in the ten year timeskip between editions.

Is there any additional information on what happened to Pseudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing definite, but during a Developer Q&A, Steve and Crystal agreed that they felt that Pseudo probably went into space to deal with Cosmic threats. However, they reserve the right to change their mind later.